# Gzip static files only once

Tags: nginx

As far as I can understand, "gzip on" zips every response (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip).

But static files don't change. Why should I zip them every time?

I would like to gzip a static file once with the maximun level of compression (9). And never touch it until its name changes (I always add a version to the file name).

Could you tell me whether it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

See
[gzip_types](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_types)
in the same webpage as your link:

> Syntax:   gzip_types mime-type ...;
> Default:  gzip_types text/html;
> Context:  http, server, location
>
> Enables gzipping of responses for the specified MIME types in addition
> to “text/html”. The special value “*” matches any MIME type (0.8.29).
> Responses with the “text/html” type are always compressed.

By default, only HTML responses are zipped. This does not pertain to
files, only to HTML pages, so files that are gzipped (or not) beforehand
are not concerned.